# How to identify a facebook default Profile Picture from response of Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph Api in PHP.

I want to check whether user profile picture is empty or not.

Currently I am getting a response with (empty **OR** Facebook Default) profile picture like this:

```
{
  "display_image": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/t31.0-1/c282.0.960.960/p960x960/10506738_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_o.jpg"
}
```

How can I identify that this Image is the one which facebook use as a default profile picture?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/

Answer (score 1):

Check the `is_silhouette` field of the picture object...

> True if the profile picture is the default 'silhouette' picture

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/